# When are log4net messages flushed from the buffer to the destination?

Tags: log4net

I'm using the [default ADONetAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html). The buffer size value is set to 100. As far as I understand, messages will be held in memory until there are 100. Then they will be flushed to their destination. Here are my questions.

1.What if only ten messages get placed into the buffer all day. Will they ever get flushed to their destination? 
2. If I'm logging from a web application, what happens when there are 50 messages in the buffer and the application pool recycles, or the web application gets republished? Do those 50 messages get lost forever? 
3. Is it *inefficient* to just set the buffer size to 1? We always set it to 1 when testing so we can see the logs ASAP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks @stuartd. If you post  your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Also, @stuartd, can you look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35323545/log4net-writing-custom-object-to-sql-database-using-custom-appender)? I notice you answer a good amout of log4net questions and I'm wondering if using the ThreadContext is appropriate. I had trouble logging the custom object when the properties weren't just strings.

Comment: Oh yes, the `12wo` question, interesting. Using ThreadContext would be OK there as long as the thread you set the value on will be the same one that does the logging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, not until the buffer count is reached, or the app ends.
2. When the app domain is torn down, the buffer is flushed to the database
3. It just means there's one database connection per log event, which can be a high overhead (and blocks the calling thread). If you have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30491358/43846) there's an example of an ADONetAppender subclass that will flush the buffer to the database after a specified time.